# How do I validate a javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, append

I'm using a small snippet of JS to add a presentational element to my blockquotes ([As seen here](http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/fun-with-css-shapes/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('blockquote.message').append('<span class="arrow" />');   
</script>
```

But the W3C validator hates that crap:

> **document type does not allow element "span" here**

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to correct this error, while maintaining the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using XHTML?  You need wrap your JavaScript in CDATA:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        $('blockquote.message').append('<span class="arrow" />');       
//]]>
</script>
```

See the XHTML reference here: http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/script/ - "If the script element contains embedded script and that script contains XHTML markup characters such as <, >, & and ", then the script should be enclosed in CDATA"

Comment: Thanks! I saw your comment on the other answer too. Does adding a span to a blockquote by javascript matter? I could also us a self-closing div if that would be better.

Comment: I honestly don't know.  It's against the spec, but the browsers will almost certainly just cope.  If you want to be sure, use a div.

Answer (score 4):

The [blockquote tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.2.2) can only contain [block elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#block) such as P, H1..n, OL/UL, PRE, DL, DIV, NOSCRIPT, BLOCKQUOTE, FORM, HR, TABLE, FIELDSET, ADDRESS

Comment: The W3C validator doesn't run the JavaScript, so it doesn't know he's adding a span to a blockquote.  It's seeing the "<span" piece of his code, interpreting it as HTML, and complaining about that.  Put it another way: the validator doesn't automatically ignore everything between <script> and </script> tags.  That's why you need CDATA.